# Issue with arrays and comparison... what to put under the if's to move the zombie towards the sp on each turn?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, comparison

```
void moveZombie(char gr[][SIZEX], int sp[], int keyMove[], int zombie[][ZOMBIECOUNT]) {
for(int i(0); i < ZOMBIECOUNT; i++) { 
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] > (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] > (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] > (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] > (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] = (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] != (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
    if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] != (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] = (sp[1] + keyMove[1]))) {

    }
```

The code above features a for loop and many ifs. Each if should be a differant option for the possible places that the zobie can go. This is a function from a program that is a pacman style game where sp is pacman and zombies blindly follow sp. Sp is controlled by the human, but zombie is automated to follow the players moves. sp moves up, down, left, right but zombie can also move diagonally. There are four zombies altogether and ZOMBIECOUNT = 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make an array of size ZOMBIECOUNT that contains the X and Y locations of the ZOMBIE, instead of an array of X and Y locations, each of which with ZOMBIECOUNT entries.

Second, calculate `sp[0] + keymove[0]` once.  Do the same for `sp[1] + keymove[1]`.  Store it in a variable with a descriptive name.

Third , `a = b` is not what you want, you want `a == b`.

Forth, work out if the `sp` is higher or lower or at the same location in x.  Then work out of the `sp` is higher or lower or at the same location in y.  Store what you worked out in an `int`, with +1 meaning "higher", -1 meaning "lower" and 0 meaning "same".  `zombieDirectionX` and `zombieDirectionY`, or a 2 element array of same.

Fifth, `zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT]` is not what you want in your conditions.  You want `zombie[0][i]` (or even `zombie[i][0]` if you reverse the order like I mentioned above).

Finally, add `zombiedirectionX` to the x coordinate of the current zombie to make it move 1 square towards the player in the x axis like this: `zombie[0][i] += zombieDirectionX`.

Comment: I think this is crucial, name the various arrays so that the names actually say something about what the array is. Until then all is confusion.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. However, how would I get -1 to mean higher, 1 to mean lower etc, in an int? The rest makes sense and is very helpful

Comment: `int dx; if (a>b) dx = 1; else if (b>a) dx = -1; else dx = 0;`

Comment: **int dx; if (zombie[0][i] > nextMove0) dx = 1; else if (nextMove0 > zombie[0][i]) dx = -1; else dx = 0;** so will this work to store the values for zombieDirection X and another for Y?

Comment: I just stored stuff in one variable, `dx`, containing the x direction between the zombie and the player.  Another similar set of if statements would be required to store the y direction.

Comment: ok, thanks. I understand that now. You have been very helpful. However, what do your a and b relate to in my program?

Comment: I have tried this now, the zombies do move ( not in the right direction though) and they eventually try to move out of the grid and I get 'A buffer overrun has occurred' as an error!

Comment: OK, I am beginning to understand the error, but when the zombie does move it moves 2 spaces each time? For example the zombie may move diagonally 2 moves rather than 1?

Answer (score 1):

Well `zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT]` is wrong. I'm guessing you meant `zombie[0][i]`. One obvious question is why you have a two dimensional array of zombies. Why isn't one dimension enough? You are doing something wrong but it's kind of hard to tell what.

The way you are using `sp` and `keyMove` looks a bit dubious too.

Comment: How could a 1d array work for storing the zombie values? Also, would sp[0] += keyMove[0] be slightly better for the sp and keymove part?

Comment: If you have a collection of books, you have a one dimensional array of books. If you have a collection of people you have a one dimensional array of people. Why would zombies be any different? You have four zombies, so a one-dimensional array of size four seems to be correct. I'm guess that what's really going on is that you have some esoteric code design in your head that makes sense to you. Unfortunately I don't think it makes sense to many other people.

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense. If I only had a 1d array how would i be able to compare the values and change them then?

Answer (score 1):

no use of index `i`  in your code.

```
for(int i(0); i < ZOMBIECOUNT; i++) { 
if (( zombie[0][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1])))
```

probably you wanted use it "somewhere" ; p, maybe:

```
for(int i(0); i < ZOMBIECOUNT; i++) { 
    if (( zombie[0][i] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (zombie[1][i] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1])))
```

also change this line:

```
&& (zombie[1][ZOMBIECOUNT] = (sp[1] + keyMove[1])))
```

probably you wanted to compare, so use `==` instead of single `=` which *assigns*.

Comment: can I ask what the 'i' is actually used for within the zombie array?

Comment: it is your code... well, if you want to iterate you have to use your index, which is "i"